# Moving a chart object amongst Modules

Tags: vba, oop, excel

I think the object orientated pattern I'm following is wrong.

Currently this is the set up

In main module:

```
Public chartOb As Excel.ChartObject

Sub ControlProcess()

  '<<other code here
  Call someComplexChartCode(chartOb)
  '<<other code here

End Sub
```

Then in a seperate module with the specialist chartobject manipulation code I have

```
' Seperate module
Sub someComplexChartCode(co As Excel.ChartObject)
  With co.Chart
    '<<chart manipulation code here
  End With
End Sub
```

Because I have a Public declaration of `chartOb` I don't think there's much need for the parameters. How do I pass the chart object around, via just args and params, without using a publicly-scoped variable?

Comment: yes, it is obviously possible. Where do you see any risk or doubt?

Comment: @KazJaw have edited OP and deleted section that said `is it possible`. Not too sure about risk just was under impression that data hiding is a good habit to get into. I will use `ByRef` as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

Because `chartOb` is globally scoped, you don't need to pass it into a function or sub for it to be visible in that function or sub.  Also, if you did not want a globally scoped chart, you could pass it.  Which is better?  That is is personal coding preference.  Personally, I like to keep thing as private as possible, so I prefer to pass variables.

Also note the distinction between passing arguments by reference `ByRef` vs by value `ByVal`  Passing by reference (which is the default for objects like a chart) passes the actual object, so changes can be made to it. Passing by value passes a copy of the object, so changes you make in your function/sub wouldn't persist.

Syntax note:  what you call "parameters" are called "arguments".

Comment: +1 thanks - in terms of syntax, if we really want to be precise (pedantic?) in my OP I have an _argument_ in here `Call someComplexChartCode(chartOb)` and I have a _parameter_ in here `someComplexChartCode(co As Excel.ChartObject)`. Many people use the terms interchangeably.

Comment: And I learned something today! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kewt1b3.aspx